# Lyx with template

Tags: lyx, templates, booktabs

after having written large parts of my dissertation in lyx - I would need to adopt a template for formatting [1](https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/members/it/faqs/latex/thesis-class) .

Can somebody tell me how to reformat my lyx document in a way as to have it in that format?

My Pramble looks like this

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\newcommand{\nm}[1]{\textnormal{#1}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What is actually your problem? In what sense you need adoption?

Comment: I don't have a full answer for you, but here are two things to bear in mind: (1) When adapting a documentclass for LyX, it's possible to change not just the LaTeX (and therefore the PDF output) but also how things look when editing in LyX, but that is probably not important if it's just you editing this document. (2) As a last resort, it's always possible to get the document broadly right in LyX, then export to LaTeX and change the documentclass etc from there.

Comment: Is there any news here? What is the real question here, or what problems do you have?